# Telegram bot survey by yield

Tags: node.js, yield, telegram-bot

I want process user responses and ask the next question.
I've used if...else, but it is bad practise, how i can use yield for it?

```
 function* gen() {
 let ask1 = yield bot.sendMessage(id, "What is Your fname?");
  bot.on("message", msg => {
      fname = msg.text;
    });

  let ask2 = yield bot.sendMessage(id, "What is Your second name?");
      bot.on("message", msg => {
        sname = msg.text;});
  }
```

But I do not understand how to call them consistently, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) in every questions, and detect `update.message.reply_to_message.text`.